# UFW Deny traffic by application

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, ufw

I want to block all traffic thats produced from an application running as a service but only on `eth0`.

My system runs Debian 8 and `ufw` as the firewall

Is it possible to deny incoming and outgoing traffic trough an application and `eth0` but still accept it on `localhost`?

I tried to use `ufw app list` but my application is not in the list.

Thanks for each answer

Comment: thanks a lot
i'll try i out